Failure in Upgrading Storybook
I am creating a npm package and now I want to upgrade the storybook to the latest version but it's giving an error.

I tried these command
npx storybook@latest upgrade  npx storybook@latest automigrate  npx storybook@8.0.9 upgrade 
